# Deleting products in cart by amount

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

I have this register application where I have to make the delete option in the basket. 
[image: Basktet]

Now I have the button set in a loop so it creates a button for each product. That all works fine, but whenever I put more than one of the same item in the basket it deletes it as well instead of making the amount less. Basically I want it to be like: cars aantal: 3 and when i click the delete button for that product aantal is 2 until its one and then delete the Item. I know that is done by setting the text for the label, but the label amount is linked to the product amount. Here is my code:

**Payment class:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
            Product product = products.get(i);
            productdelete = product;

lblamount = new JLabel(String.valueOf(WinkelApplication.getBasket().getProductAmount(productdelete)));
            lblamount.setBounds(410, verticalPosition + i * productOffset, 70, 20);
            lblamount.setFont(WinkelApplication.FONT_10_PLAIN);
            add(lblamount);

DeleteProduct deleteproduct = new DeleteProduct();

            JButton btnDeleteproduct = new JButton("X");
            btnDeleteproduct.setBounds(380, verticalPosition + i * productOffset, 20, 20);
            btnDeleteproduct.setFont(WinkelApplication.FONT_10_BOLD);
            btnDeleteproduct.setName("" + i);
            btnDeleteproduct.addActionListener(deleteproduct);
            add(btnDeleteproduct);
}
```

**DeleteProduct class:**

```
public void productlist(){
    List<Product> products = WinkelApplication.getBasket().getProducts();

    for(int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++){
        deleteproduct = products.get(i);
    }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        productlist();

        productamount = WinkelApplication.getBasket().getProductAmount(deleteproduct);

        if(productamount == 1){
            WinkelApplication.getBasket().deleteProduct(deleteproduct);
        }else if (productamount > 1){
            productamount--;
            WinkelApplication.getBasket().setProductAmount(productamount);
            WinkelApplication.getInstance().showPanel(new view.Payment());
        }

    }
```

And whenever I put this code somewhere else to load:

```
productamount = WinkelApplication.getBasket().getProductAmount(deleteproduct);
```

it gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at model.Basket.getProductAmount(Basket.java:62)
    at view.DeleteProduct.productlist(DeleteProduct.java:27)
    at view.DeleteProduct.actionPerformed(DeleteProduct.java:34)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6382)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6147)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:663)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:661)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: (offtopic) Just a simple brotip: "damesonderbroek" is spelled without the space in Dutch ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

clearly shows that the object you are trying to get is null try to put null check 
   if(WinkelApplication.getBasket()!=null)

Comment: I have done the check with a system out, but the system out is not shown. The thing is I load the amount in an int variable, that will give me for example 3. Then after that I decrement the variable by one and set the product amount with the decremented variable. Yet everytime the productamount jumps to 3 again so it overwrites, but I don't know how I can make sure the amount is set in a different class without overwriting.

Comment: Thanks! That will help me understand what that does, still the problem is not solved because I need to get it working that the amount is decremented if the item is more than 1. I hope you can help me with that also!

Comment: you have to manage it differently because you had given delete button that means you want to delete all items not a single item of same type